# Creating a new record with POST gives error: Got a TypeError when calling Product.objects.create()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework and have the folowing view class to view or create product. Now I'm trying to add a new record with POST method, but I get the error below. Can anyone tell me why and how can I fix this?

updated .   ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌

```
TypeError at /store/view/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Product.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Product.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ProductSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

view class:

```
class StoreApiView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Product.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(description__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        return qs

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, context={'request': self.request})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and the related serializer class:

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product_ratings = ProductRatingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    product_badges_set = ProductBadgesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.first_name + ' ' + obj.author.last_name

    def get_category(self, obj):
        return obj.category.title

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'product_id',
            'author',
            'title',
            'mini_description',
            'you_learn',
            'you_need',
            'full_description',
            'price',
            'video_level',
            'video_length',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
            'product_ratings',
            'product_badges_set',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['product_id', 'created_date', 'updated_date', 'author','product_badges_set',
                            'product_ratings']
```

model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    video_length = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    mini_description = models.CharField(max_length=220, null=True, blank=True)
    full_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    you_need = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    you_learn = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    video_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self.author
```

Comment: post your product model

Comment: post updated . . .

Comment: What do you want to achieve with adding `context` to the method `perform_create` in your view? What happens if you leave it out, like this: `serializer.save(author=self.request.user)`?

Comment: @cezar i have a validation for title and i want check request method is post to perform validation only in post request like this :

```
 def validate_title(self, value):
        if self.context['request']._request.method == 'POST':
           ...
```

Comment: Please try it out as I in my example. I think you don't need to pass the request to the context, it should be available in the validation method per default.

Comment: @moh would you please like to provide feedback on your progress? Cheers!

Comment: @cezar the issue fixed but now im trying to save my uploded file to a dynamic directory can you please help me ?

Comment: I can't see in your examples where do you upload a file. Eventually you should open another question specifically for that issue. If you have solved your problem, please post your own answer and explain what helped and how the issue was solved, then accept your own answer. In that way you'll help other people having a similar problem and the quality of SO will increase. It is ugly when we have too many unanswered and open questions, which in fact have been solved.

Comment: @cezar ok i remember this . i updated my new question can you please check it :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974662/save-upload-file-to-dynamic-directory-and-get-the-path-for-store-in-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people who have similar problem this problem refer to passin the request in context in my code i replace it with below code according to cezar's comment.

serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

thankyou