# save upload file to dynamic directory and get the path for store in db

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm uploading a file and additionally some data like file's id and file's title to the server. I have the view below to handle the request and I want to save the file to a dynamic path like `upload/user_id/thefile.txt`.

With code the below the file will be saved in and upload folder directly and also my `product_video` table will create a new record with the related id and the title.
Now I don't have any idea how can I save the file in a dynamically generated directory like: `upload/user_id/thefile.txt` and how to save the produced path to the database table column `video_path`?

view class:

```
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
            myfile = request.FILES['file']
            serilizer = VideoSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serilizer.is_valid():
                serilizer.save()

            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)

            return Response("ok")

        return Response("bad")
```

and serializer clas:

```
class VideoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product_Video
        fields = [
            'p_id',
            'title',
            'video_length',
            'is_free',
        ]
```

and related model class:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class Product_Video(models.Model):
    p_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='product_id', related_name='product_video')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True,blank=True)
    video_path = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to=user_directory_path,storage=FileSystemStorage)
    video_length = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: There are many flows in your code. The main problem is that you use `user_directory_path` in your view. You should use it only in the model (in the `FileField`). Also the instance has no `user` attribute, so you'll run again into problems.

Comment: ahh let me undo my update ...  cause it didnt work i thoght maybe we need use the function again in view i will replace it with my last code now

Comment: @cezar this is my old codes can you please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the cart before the horse. Start from the beginning, first things first. And the first thing is the user story, then the model layer.

There are **Products** and a **Product** can have many **ProductVideos**. A **Product** has an **Author** (the **Author** can have many **Products**). When you upload a **ProductVideo** for a particular **Product**, you want to save it in a directory which contains the **Author** ID.

Therefore we specify a callable for the `FileField` which should dynamically find out the `id` of the **Author**:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # get the id of the author
    # first get the Product, then get its author's id
    user_id = str(instance.p_id.author.id)
    # little bit cosmetics
    # should the filename be in uppercase
    filename = filename.lower()
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(user_id, filename)
```

When saving an instance of `Product_Video` the uploaded file should be stored in a directory with a dynamically created pathname based on the author's ID.

Further I'd suggest you to follow established coding conventions:

- don't use `snake_case` for class names, especially don't mix it with capital letters. Use `PascalCase`, preferably singular nouns, for class names: `ProductVideo`
- if your model class is `ProductVideo`, keep that name in all subsequent classes: `ProductVideoSerializer` for the model serializer and `ProductVideoAPIView` for the generic view.
- use verbs for methods and standalone functions, `get_user_directory` or `upload_to_custom_path` is better than `user_directory_path`.
- also avoid suffixing the foreign key fields with `_id`. Use rather `product` instead of `p_id`. Django will allow you to access the related object by calling `product` and get the id of the object by calling `product_id`. Using the name `p_id` means you'll access the id of the related object by calling `p_id_id` which looks very weird and confusing.

Comment: thankyou do you have any advice about the model fields ? for example do you prefer productAllTags or product_all_tags or something else it will become our tables name in db

Comment: @moh It isn't about what I do prefer, it is about python coding conventions [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Model fields are class attributes and they are always written in `snake_case`. Thus you would use `product_all_tags`. Camel case as in `productAllTags` isn't used in Python. It's only the class names that are written in pascal case (`PascalCase`).